# NoClassDefFoundError with own .java in "unpackaged" test class

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to generate a pdf file.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

class HelloWordPDF
 {      

             public static void main(String []args) throws FileNotFoundException,DocumentException
            {


                          Document document=new Document();
                          PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("hello.pdf"));
                          document.open();
                          document.add(new Paragraph("Hello Pdf"));
                          document.close();
            }
    }
```

This java program is in the directory **/home/Jagan/HelloWordPDF.java**
and the jar file   **/home/Jagan/iText-5.0.6.jar**

It is compiled successfully **$ javac -cp iText-5.0.6.jar HelloWordPDF.java**

But when i tried to run  **$java -cp iText-5.0.6.jar HelloWordPDF**

An exception occured like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWordPDF/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWordPDF.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
Could not find the main class: HelloWordPDF.java. Program will exit.
```

Comment: try `$javac -jar iText-5.0.6.jar HelloWordPDF.java` & `$java -jar iText-5.0.6.jar HelloWordPDF`

Comment: You should be outside the package directory and then execute the run command.

Comment: Try this java -cp iText-5.0.6.jar;. home.Jagan.HelloWordPDF

Comment: @Ashish : This is the error i am getting   when i run                          java -cp iText-5.0.6.jar;. /home/Jagan/HelloWordPDF
bash: /home/Jagan/HelloWordPDF: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jagan You should be outside the package directory and then execute the run command. If you are running this command from the Jagan directory , it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also include the directory of the class you want to execute to the classpath because as it is it searches only inside the iText-5.0.6.jar, so try using

```
java -cp iText-5.0.6.jar;. HelloWordPDF
```

if the HelloWordPDF.class is in the current directory.

Comment: java -cp /home/Jagan/iText-5.0.6.jar  /home/Jagan/HelloWordPDF
I even tried like this but no result

Comment: Hello ! i got it .... thanks! "java -cp iText-5.0.6.jar:. HelloWordPDF". For appending class path colon should be used(not semi-colon)

Comment: @jagan - the classpath separator is os dependent.  ":" is unix-ish, ";" is windows.